# Benefits using server response parameters as custom headers

Tags: ios, http, custom-headers

In my `iOS` mobile application through `NSURLConnection`

I have couple of simple `HTTP` requests to backend and I'm getting `HTTP` response which includes response body.

This body has `JSON` parameters which I parse and map to in-app objects.

```
{"some_parameter": "some_value"}
```

For my purposes that is pretty enough, but -
I'm wondering what are benefits to have needed parameters defined as custom headers:

```
X-Some-Parameter: some_value
```

on `HTTP` response comparing to response body?

Is it good to use all parameters as custom headers?

Comment: General convention is to use all parameters as regular GET/POST pairs. Custom headers are only used in special cases like Authorization, Content type etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good practice to generally separate the business logic of your application from HTTP headers which are used to describe meta data regarding the body itself. I don't see any added value for breaking this abstraction of layers - not in your requests and not in the server responses.